# Can the const be applied to types?

Tags: c, constants, c99

I've known that `const` qualifier only affects an object but not it's type:

For example:

```
// Only the elements of an array are constant not the array itself
const int a[5];
```

Suppose if I had:

```
float *const p1; // 1
float const *p2; // 2
```

In the first case above, does it mean that pointer *type* is constant and not the object `p1`? How can this be when the types aren't allowed to be qualified?

Comment: "*I've known that `const` qualifier only affects an object but not it's type*" - this is wrong.

Comment: @melpomene: For example? Is it not correct to say that const only affects an array object and not it's type?

Comment: That is indeed not correct.

Comment: You also chose a bad example.  Arrays cannot be assigned to, so it is in fact implicitly const.

Comment: I like to say "arrays have no mutable structure". It doesn't really matter whether it's const or not if there is nothing to modify.

Comment: @melpomene: How about an example in which const affects the type and not the object of that type? I'm not sure If I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float *const p1; // 1
```

Means that the pointer `p1` is constant and it cannot(rather should not) point to another address.
It is not the pointer *type* that is constant but the instance of this type which is `p1` that is contant.

Use the **[Clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)** to understand this better.

> **How can this be when the types aren't allowed to be qualified?**

This is not correct. In fact, qualifier is a short form for *type qualifier*(§6.7.3)

Comment: Since a pointer is a derived type. Does this statement seem to be relevant here? _"(§ 6.2.5/26) A derived type is not qualified by the qualifiers (if any) of the type from which it is derived."_

Answer (score 1):

With this declaration:

```
const int a[5];
```

a has type "array of 5 const ints".

With this declaration

```
float *const p1;
```

p1 has type "const pointer to float".

With this declaration

```
const float *p2;
```

p2 has type "pointer to const float".

There is no way to declare an array as const, but an array can't be changed anyway.  Only the elements in an array can be changed.